# is there any way to tell npm to not remove a module folder on update?

Tags: module, npm, bower, destroy

I've created a node module that uses folders such as "images/" , "uploads/" etc.

I need these folders reside in the same module folder and won't be destroyed whenever there is a new version of the module running the command "npm update"

i've tried also using Bower but they use the same approach of "destroy everything and replace"

is there any way to accomplish my requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a nice solution proposed by this bower's fork using "keep" feature!

https://github.com/hyperweb2/upt